# Why cube mesh becomes a plane when in high resolution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, procedural-generation

I use the following code to generate a Cube as a single mesh. My purpose is to generate a sphere from it by normalizing as I have shown in the commented line (I just have to do that to all those statements in the following lines). The problem here is that the mesh changes from a cube to a flat plane as I keep increasing the resolution (parameter given as `public int resolution`).

(This code was inspired by this video https://youtu.be/QN39W020LqU . But I am using the technique in my own way as given by the following code, so that I can generate a single mesh instead of a combination of 6 meshes, this is required for my work)

```
[code=CSharp]
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sc_Planet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(2, 512)]
    public int resolution = 2;

    [Range(2, 256)]
    public int radius = 10;

    MeshFilter meshFilter;

    void OnValidate()
    {
        Initialize();
    }


    void Initialize()
    {
        if (meshFilter == null)
        {
            GameObject meshObj = new GameObject("mesh_Planet");
            meshObj.transform.parent = transform;

            meshObj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
            meshFilter = meshObj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
            meshFilter.sharedMesh = new Mesh();
        }

        int xmax = resolution + 1;
        int ymax = resolution + 1;

        float dx = 1.0f / resolution;
        float dy = 1.0f / resolution;

        Vector3[] vertsTop = new Vector3[xmax * ymax];
        Vector3[] vertsRight = new Vector3[xmax * ymax];
        Vector3[] vertsFront = new Vector3[xmax * ymax];
        Vector3[] vertsBottom = new Vector3[xmax * ymax];
        Vector3[] vertsLeft = new Vector3[xmax * ymax];
        Vector3[] vertsBack = new Vector3[xmax * ymax];

        for (int y = 0; y < ymax; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xmax; x++)
            {
                float px = dx * x - 0.5f;
                float py = dy * y - 0.5f;
                int t = x + y * xmax;

                //vertsTop[t] = new Vector3(py, 0.5f, px).normalized * radius;

                vertsTop[t] = new Vector3(py, 0.5f, px);
                vertsRight[t] = new Vector3(px, py, 0.5f);
                vertsFront[t] = new Vector3(0.5f, px, py);

                vertsBottom[t] = new Vector3(px, -0.5f, py);
                vertsLeft[t] = new Vector3(py, px, -0.5f);
                vertsBack[t] = new Vector3(-0.5f, py, px);
            }
        }

        List<int> trianglesList = new List<int>();
        for (int y = 0; y < ymax - 1; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xmax; ++x)
            {
                if (x % xmax != xmax - 1)
                {
                    int f = x + y * xmax;

                    trianglesList.Add(f);
                    trianglesList.Add(f + 1);
                    trianglesList.Add(f + 1 + xmax);

                    trianglesList.Add(f);
                    trianglesList.Add(f + 1 + xmax);
                    trianglesList.Add(f + xmax);
                }
            }
        }

        List<Vector3> verts = new List<Vector3>();
        Dictionary<Vector3, int> vdict = new Dictionary<Vector3, int>();
        List<int> triangles = new List<int>();
        int nextIndex = 0;

        void addFace(Vector3 [] in_verts, List<int> in_triangles)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < in_verts.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (!vdict.ContainsKey(in_verts[i]))
                {
                    vdict.Add(in_verts[i], nextIndex);
                    verts.Add(in_verts[i]);
                    ++nextIndex;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < in_triangles.Count; ++i)
            {
                triangles.Add(vdict[in_verts[in_triangles[i]]]);
            }
        }

        addFace(vertsTop, trianglesList);
        addFace(vertsRight, trianglesList);
        addFace(vertsFront, trianglesList);
        addFace(vertsBottom, trianglesList);
        addFace(vertsLeft, trianglesList);
        addFace(vertsBack, trianglesList);


        var mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = verts.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
[/code]
```

This code works in Blender (I used python to script it on Blender and it works very well for any resolution).
The only problem is that when I use this in Unity, the meshes become weird as I have shown in the images I have attached below.

At Resolution = 96 :
[image]

At Resolution = 122 :
[image]

At Resolution = 182 :
[image]

At Resolution = 344:
[image]

Why is this happening?
How should I correct it?

(I have also posted this in unity forums: [Why cube mesh becomes a plane when in high resolution?](https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-cube-mesh-becomes-a-plane-when-in-high-resolution.1187254/))

Comment: It doesn't become a plane, as you can see the faces are screwed-up when the res increases.

Comment: You can start with this: `float px = dx * x - 0.5f;` => `float px = dx * (x - 0.5f);` Same for `py` I see more calculation without parentesis.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen No that calculation is correct. What I need there is exactly `(dx * x) - 0.5f`. The problem only occurs at higher resolutions than 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. This is exceeding the limit of vertices on unity api for 16-bit based meshes. I had to change it to a 32-bit indexed mesh to correct it.

Details are in this docuemntaiton page : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.IndexFormat.html?_ga=2.9556401.501737799.1635227368-67181881.1629608252

I just had to add the code :

`mesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;`

That was it.